# Transfering specific data from one workbook to another

Tags: .net, vba, excel

I have made a piece of code with VBA that will transfer data from one workbook to another without taking the function with it. Every time it is ran, it doesn't seem to want to put out the correct information. Could you guys take a look at it and tell me what you see wrong?

```
Sub transfer()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim lastrow1 As Long
  Dim lastrow2 As Long
  Dim jobnum As String
  Dim mainmachine As String
  Dim WBT As Workbook ''This Workbook CNC PL
  Dim WBC As Workbook '' New workbook CapacitySummary

  Set WBT = Workbooks("CNC TEST.xlsx")
  Set WBC = Workbooks("CapacitySummary.xlsx")
  lastrow1 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastrow2 = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  WBT.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
  For i = 2 To lastrow1
    jobnum = WBT.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
    mainmachine = WBT.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K").Value
    WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Activate


    For j = 2 To lastrow2

      If WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, "A").Value = jobnum And 
        WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, "B").Value = mainmachine Then
        '''' Comparing data between workbooks
        WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Activate
        WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(i, "N"), Cells(i, "N")).Copy
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ''''Choosing Range to copy
        WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, "P"), Cells(j, "P")).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ''''Choosing Range to paste
      End If

    Next j
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Next i

End sub
```

[image: Priority List]

[image: Capacity]

So, What we want to do is have the macro check both workbooks and see if the "JobNumbers" are matching. If so, we want it to check if the "Mach Center" on the Capacity and "Current WC" on the Priority List is matching. If it does, We want to copy the total time on the capacity list and paste it on Column "P" on the priority list (CNC Dept) without the function copying over with it.

Comment: See [mcve]. SO isn't a "please debug my code for me" service.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of errors found.  mainly I don't understand the following two lines.  They use a lot of code to apparently point to a single cell.

```
WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(i, "N"), Cells(i, "N")).Copy
WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, "P"), Cells(j, "P")).Select
```

Also I would suggest coding without ever using the word select or activate.  Slows it down.  Try the following code and see if it works for what you need.

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim jobnum As String
Dim mainmachine As String
Dim WBT As Workbook ''This Workbook CNC PL
Dim WBC As Workbook '' New workbook CapacitySummary

Set WBT = Workbooks("CNC TEST.xlsx")
Set WBC = Workbooks("CapacitySummary.xlsx")
lastrow1 = WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
jobnum = WBT.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
mainmachine = WBT.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K").Value


For j = 2 To lastrow2

If WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, "A").Value = jobnum And _
WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, "B").Value = mainmachine Then
'''' Comparing data between workbooks
WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Activate
'WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(i, "N"), Cells(i, "N")).Copy Destination:=WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, "P"), Cells(j, "P"))

WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & j) = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Range("N" & i)
'ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
''''Choosing Range to copy
'WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
'WBT.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, "P"), Cells(j, "P")).Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste

''''Choosing Range to paste
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code. Its been adjusted to avoid and .select, .activate or .copy commands.

```
Dim WBT As Excel.Workbook
Dim WBC As Excel.Workbook
Dim jobNumWBT As String
Dim jonNumWBC As String
Dim mainMachine As String
Dim machCenter As String
Dim WBTpath As String
Dim WBCpath As String

WBTpath = "[insert your path here]"
WBCpath = "[insert your path here]"

Set WBT = GetObject(WBTpath)
Set WBC = GetObject(WBCpath)

For i = 2 To WBT.Worksheets(1).Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    jobNumWBT = WBT.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    mainMachine = WBT.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Value 'current WC
    For j = 2 To WBC.Worksheets(1).Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        jobNumWBC = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, 1).Value
        machCenter = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, 2).Value
        totalTime = WBC.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(j, 14).Value

        If jobNumWBT = jobNumWBC And machCenter = mainMachine Then
            WBT.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 16).Value = totalTime
        End If

    Next j
Next i

WBT.Save
WBC.Save
WBT.Close
WBC.Close
```